# Extending the domain of the Dirichlet form associated with a symmetric Markov semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
- $\mathcal M_b(E,\mathcal E):=\left\{f:E\to\mathbb R\mid f\text{ is bounded and }\mathcal E\text{-measurable}\right\}$
- $(P_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Markov semigroup on $(E,\mathcal E)$ and $$P_tf:=\int P_t(\;\cdot\;,{\rm d}y)f(y)\tag1$$ for $f\in\mathcal M_b(E,\mathcal E)$ and $t\ge0$
- $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ subinvariant with respect to $(P_t)_{t\ge0}$

It's easy to see that $(P_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a contraction semigroup on $\left(\mathcal M_b(E,\mathcal E),\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}\right)$ and hence has a unique extension to a contraction semigroup on $L^2(\mu)$. Let $(\mathcal D(L),L)$ denote the generator of that semigroup, $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal D(L)$ be closed under multiplication and $$\Gamma(f,g):=\frac12(L(fg)-fLg-gLf)\;\;\;\text{for }f,g\in\mathcal A.$$ Assume $\mu$ is reversible with respect to $(P_t)_{t\ge0}$ and hence $$\mathcal E(f,g):=\int\Gamma(f,g)\:{\rm d}\mu=-\langle f,Lg\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}=-\langle Lf,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}\;\;\;\text{for all }f,g\in\mathcal A\tag2.$$

> In the book [*Analysis and Geometry of Markov Diffusion Operators*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319002262) the authors write the following:
>
> [image: Dirichlet form]
>
> How can we verify the first equality (stressing the fact that $f\in L^2(\mu)$ and not $f\in\mathcal D(A)$)?

Clearly, $$\varphi:L^2(\mu)\to L^1(\mu)\;,\;\;\;f\mapsto f^2$$ is Fréchet differentiable with derivative $${\rm D}\varphi:L^2(\mu)\to\mathfrak L(L^2(\mu),L^1(\mu))\;,\;\;\;f\mapsto(g\mapsto 2fg)$$ and hence it should be just differentiation under the integral sign. However, don't we need the orbit $$\operatorname{orb}f:[0,\infty)\to L^2(\mu)\;,\;\;\;f\mapsto P_tf$$ to be differentiable for that? That should require $f\in\mathcal D(L)$ ...

Answer (score 1):

If the semigroup $(P_t)$ is symmetric in $L^2(\mu)$, then the generator $A$ is self-adjoint. In this case, $P_t$ maps into $D(A)$ for all $t>0$. In particular, $t\mapsto P_t f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$. This can be verified using the spectral theorem:

Denote by $\nu_f$ the spectral measure of $f\in L^2$. For $t>0$ one has
$$
\int_{(-\infty,0]}\lambda^2e^{2t\lambda}\,d\nu_f(\lambda)\leq \frac{1}{e^2t^2}\nu_f((-\infty,0])=\frac{\|f\|_2^2}{e^2t^2}.
$$
Thus $P_t f=e^{tA}f\in D(A)$ and $\|AP_t f\|_2^2\leq e^{-2}t^{-2}\|f\|_2^2$.

Similarly, the equality $\partial_t \|P_t f\|_2^2=-2\mathcal{E}(P_t f)$ can be verified (just write both sides as integrals with respect to the spectral measure and use the dominated convergence theorem to check that you can interchange integration and differentiation).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89511/discussion-on-answer-by-maowao-extending-the-domain-of-the-dirichlet-form-associ).

Comment: Regarding my first question: In the case where $\psi$ is unbounded, the integral $\int\psi(\lambda)\:{\rm d}\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle_H$ is defined (for fixed $x,y$) if $$\int|\psi(\lambda)|\:|{\rm d}\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle_H|<\infty.$$ If I take a look at how they intend to define the operator $\Psi$, it would make more sense to me if we define its domain to be $\left\{x\in H\mid\forall y\in H:\int|\psi(\lambda)|\:|{\rm d}\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle_H|<\infty\right\}$. Is this domain equal to $\left\{x\in H:\int|\psi(\lambda)|^2\:|{\rm d}\langle E_λx,x\rangle_H|<\infty\right\}$?

Comment: Just another thought: I get that since $A$ is densely-defined, nonnegative and self-adjoint, it's spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is contained in $[0,\infty)$. (On the other hand, our $A$ is even the generator of a contraction semigroup and hence its resolvent set $\rho(A)$ is contained in $(0,\infty)$; Is this just the same information stated differently (noting that $\sigma(A)=\mathbb R\setminus\rho(A))$ or does it given more information about $\sigma(A)$?). The spectral measure (as I understand it) is now defined on $\mathcal B([0,\infty))$. So, why do we need to extend

Comment: integrands $\psi:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ by $0$ on $(-\infty,0)$? Moreover, if (as stated in the book), we set $E_\lambda=0$ for all $\lambda<0$, shouldn't we automatically get $\int_{\mathbb R}\psi(\lambda)\:{\rm d}\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle_H=\int_{[0,\infty)}\psi(\lambda)\:{\rm d}\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle_H$? Since you're integrating over $(-\infty,0]$, I guess I'm missing something crucial ...

Comment: Regarding your first comment: No, that's not the same. The problem is that you also want to evaluate expressions of the form $\langle Ax,Ax\rangle$, and your integrability condition is not enough for that. The problem in your second and third comment lies in the typical confusion of signs of the generator. I used the spectral theorem for $A$, the book used it for $-A$ (both operators are sometimes called the generator, depending on the author). You can either define the spectral measure on all of $\mathbb{R}$ or only on a measurable subset containing the spectrum, that does not matter.

Comment: In any case, it is probably better if you pick up a decent textbook that treats the spectral theorem not only in its appendix (for example Reed-Simon or the very nice, but not so direct approach in Conway's functional analysis; the book by Teschl is also quite good and freely available on his webpage) and ask new questions along the way. The spectral theorem is not a topic to be lectured on in the comment section (plus it is really useful to know).

Comment: Instead of defining the integral in the context of the spectral measure relative to the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure given by the right-continuous bounded variation function $\lambda\mapsto\langle E_\lambda x,y\rangle$ (and then using Riesz' representation theorem to show that there is an operator as defined in the spectral theorem), we could integrate against the Lebesgue-Stieltjes (vector) measure induced by $\lambda\mapsto E_\lambda x$ (which is right-continuous and of bounded variation too). Are these two approaches equivalent?

Comment: It seems to me they are not (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3137835/47771), while my intuition would be that they should.